# Custom made Switch is not showing on Android KitKat 4.4.4

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-4.4-kitkat

I've made custom Switch which is working fine on all android versions except KitKat. Its not on KitKat 4.4.4 screen. How can I make it visible on KitKat ? Any help would be great !

xml code :

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_missed"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:text="Enable Missed Calls "
    android:gravity="left"
    android:thumbTextPadding="25dp"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:track="@drawable/rectangle_track"
    android:thumb="@drawable/rectangle_thumb"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

rectangle_track.xml : 


   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorGreyGreen"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorSilver"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

rectangle_thumb :

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"      
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        <size android:height="24dp" android:width="24dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: can you use Support Switch instead and see if that works `https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/SwitchCompat`

Comment: also can you tell if rectangle_track and rectangle_thumb is a vector or not? vector are not supported on kitkat. If that's the case, you might need to make a customswitch with vector supported.

Comment: I have edited .. now you can see my rectangle_track.xml

Comment: can you put ractangle_thumb also? I'll like to produce this myself.

Comment: without the rectangle_thumb, I can see it in preview pane of android studio for api 19.

Comment: Edited. I have added rectangle_thumb too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact details but SwitchCompat seems working with KK 19.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_missed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Enable Missed Calls "
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:thumbTextPadding="25dp"
    app:track="@drawable/rectangle_track"
    android:thumb="@drawable/rectangle_thumb"
    tools:checked="true" />
```

Comment: Problem solved ! But do SwitchCompat works perfectly for all android versions ?

Comment: yes. it works on all android versions. (as long as you have latest support library)